# client event handler for sending message to groups in SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to integrate SignalR in my MVC project and everything works fine,
however ther is something I can't get right,
Using the latest version of signalR:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/announcing-the-release-of-signalr-0-5-3.aspx

And writing the group functionality described in this wiki:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs

Especifically in thr MANAGING GROUPS topic, there is the following code to send a message to a specific group:

```
    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return Clients.Group("foo").addMessage(message);
    }
```

I can't figure two things: as the way the code is stated I have the following exception:

```
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object>' does not contain a definition for 'addMessage'
```

Besides that, what exactly is the event raised in the client to handle it properly with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. The documentation is updated to be the latest release which is 1.0 alpha2. http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/11/11/microsoft-asp-net-signalr.aspx.

To install it do:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -pre
```

We're going to be deprecating the older packages soon.